# ¿cómo colocar evitar que se coloquen en minuscula las letras?

Tags: php

lo que sucede es que almaceno esto en una variable en php:

```js
$datos = "<tem:ObtenerDatosVehiculoPropietario>"
    . "<tem:obtenerDatosVehiculoPropietarioPeticion>"
    . "<apl:NumeroChasis></apl:NumeroChasis>"
    . "<apl:NumeroDocumento>$documento</apl:NumeroDocumento>"
    . "<apl:TipoDocumento>C</apl:TipoDocumento>"
    . "</tem:obtenerDatosVehiculoPropietarioPeticion>"
    . "</tem:ObtenerDatosVehiculoPropietario>";
```

pero cuando lo voy a imprimir me sale asi:

```js
<tem:obtenerdatosvehiculopropietario><tem:obtenerdatosvehiculopropietariopeticion><apl:numerochasis></apl:numerochasis><apl:numerodocumento>22129614</apl:numerodocumento><apl:tipodocumento>C</apl:tipodocumento></tem:obtenerdatosvehiculopropietariopeticion></tem:obtenerdatosvehiculopropietario>
```

todo en minúscula y yo quisiera poder conservar las mayúsculas ¿como puedo hacer para que no se me cambien las mayúsculas por minúsculas?, agradezco su ayuda de antemano.

Comment: ¿Con qué código lo imprimes?

Comment: lo imprimo con echo $datos;

Comment: aunque también lo intente con print_r($datos); y tampoco sigue saliendo en minúscula

Comment: ¿Seguro? Prueba en un documento simple, que sea nuevo, sin reglas CSS ni nada. A mi se me imprime bien. Debes tener algo, a algún framework o librería que convierte a minúscula.

Comment: Si, cuando inspecciono el elemento para observar las etiquetas todas quedan en minúscula, probé en un nuevo proyecto sin nada mas que esa variable en php y me sigue apareciendo en minúscula.